# Getting started with the Halide programming language?

Tags: c++, image-processing, installation, halide

I'm trying to get started with a **domain-specific language (C++ extension) for image processing** called [**Halide**](http://halide-lang.org/).

Following the [Halide README](https://github.com/halide/Halide#readme), here's what I've tried:

1. Downloaded the [Ubuntu 12.04 Halide binary](https://github.com/halide/Halide/downloads), and extracted in a directory called `~/halide`.
2. In the `~/halide` directory, I created `hello_halide.cpp`, as described in the `Using Halide` section of [this page](https://github.com/halide/Halide#readme).
3. Tried to compile `hello_halide.cpp`:

   `g++-4.6 -std=c++0x hello_halide.cpp -L halide -lHalide -ldl -lpthread -o hello_halide`

   But, g++ can't find libhalide:

   `/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lHalide`
4. Tried adding `~/halide` to my `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but this didn't help.

**How can I compile this basic `hello_halide.cpp` Halide program?**

---

Notes:

- CUDA is one of Halide's dependencies. I have CUDA installed, and I can compile/run CUDA programs.
- I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.
- My g++ version is 4.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-L halide` tells the linker to look for the library in the subdirectory `halide`. In this case that means that your source file `hello_halide.cpp` should be in a folder `~/myfolder/`, and the library `libHalide.so` at `~/myfolder/halide/libHalide.so` (or `.a` if it's static). If it's somewhere else, pass an absolute path to `-L`.

Your idea of setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `PATH` does not work since the latter is for directories that will be searched for executables and the former is for directories that will be searched for shared libraries *when you launch an executable that needs shared libraries*.